# Recursion - Finding the Amount of Even Digits in a Number

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having trouble with this problem. I am supposed to find the amount of even digits in a number.

So for example, if the number is 146, then there are 2 even digits.

And if the number is 802, then there are 3 even digits.

I was told that n % 10 is the value of the rightmost digit. n / 10 contains all of the digits except the rightmost digit.

```
public static int countEvenDigits(int n) {

     int rightDigit =  n % 10;
     int count= 0;


     if (rightDigit / 10 == 0) {
           count++;
     } 

     return countEvenDigits(count);
 }
```

Comment: Is recursion a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

With recursion, you can do it like this

```
int calcRec(int num) {

    if (num / 10 == 0) {
        return num % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }else{
        return (num % 10 % 2 == 0? 1:0)+calcRec(num/10);
    }

}
```

But its not suitable case for using recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer:

```
public static int countEvenDigits(int number) {
    if (number == 0) return 0;
    int lastDigit = number % 10;
    int firstDigits = number / 10;
    if (lastDigit % 2 == 0) {
        return 1 + countEvenDigits(firstDigits);
    } else {
        return 0 + countEvenDigits(firstDigits);
    }
}
```

Recursion always needs one or more "base case"s, where recursion stops (in this case, no digits left); and one or more "recursive cases" where you continue to work with a smaller problem (with the `firstDigits`).

I agree with @kimreik that this is not a good use of recursion (as the problem could be better solved with a while-loop); but it is a very typical example when starting to learn to program recursion, as I suspect the OP is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the idea of using recursion to process a series is that you define a function that process and removes one element from the set. Seeing as you are interested in digits you have 2 options to define your set from a given int.

The first option is to cast the int to a string and cast each character back into an int. Which is what I implemented below

Alternatively you could do division by your base (10) to the power of the significance of the digit (0 being the right most digit and counting left.) Or more eloquently as kimreik reducing the number by integer division sequentially. (142 / 10 / 10 == 142 / 100 == 1 == "142"[0])...

The syntax for converting your integer to a string is `Integer.toString(int)`. This will be useful as it allows us to access each digit without doing any math and also allows us to take sub-strings which we can pass to the next instance of our recursive method.

Now that we have our array to process we need to address the fundamentals of recursion. Recursion has three parts. These parts are as follows, some starting state or initial values, a base case and a recursive step.

For this problem we must set our initial values for the count of even digits and we will be given a string to process. We will start our count at 0 but it will be a variable passed to each call to our method.

Our base case is the empty sting, that is a blank number. Which contains 0 even numbers. Because we are recurring towards an empty set this type of algorithm is called reductive.

Now our recursive step is where everything really happens. It must read a digit from our string and then remove it from the string by passing the remaining digits to the next instance of the function.

Now that we know what we need to do what does out function look like?

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static int recursiveGetEvenDigits(String arg){
        int count = 0;
        if(arg.length()<1){
             return(0); // base case
        }
        else{
             count = Character.getNumericValue(arg.charAt(0))%2 == 0 ? 1 : 0; //If else shorthand
             return(count+recursiveGetEvenDigits(arg.substring(1)));
        }
    }
    public static int getEvenDigits(int n){ // provide user arguments
        return(recursiveGetEvenDigits(Integer.toString(n))); // set initial conditions
    }
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(getEvenDigits(142));
     }
}
```

Just to be funny the whole if else logic could be reduced to one line again with the same shorthand I used above.

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static int recursiveGetEvenDigits(String arg){
        return arg.length() < 1 ? 0 : (Character.getNumericValue(arg.charAt(0)) % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0)+recursiveGetEvenDigits(arg.substring(1));
    }
    public static int getEvenDigits(int n){ // provide user arguments
        return(recursiveGetEvenDigits(Integer.toString(n))); // set initial conditions
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(getEvenDigits(142));
    }
}
```

prints `2`

Comment: Your answer is correct, but overly long given the OP's question. Also, OP is using ints, and you are using strings instead. At OP's probable level of coding, this probably makes a big difference.

Comment: I think it's important to understand both approaches. If the op is a newbie, all the better.

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick pseudo code

```
function sumEven(int num){
        if(num==0)
            return 0;

        int var =num%10;

        if(var % 2)
            return var+(num/10)
        else
            return 0+(num/10)
}
```